# PostgreSQL to find the next available value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have followed the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35364442/364056) to find the next available value on a table column: the generated value will be used by an application to insert data in another table. But, if multiple concurrent application instances run the same query, some of these instances could get the same value. How could I avoid these collisions without change the application? Is it possible write a PostreSQL function to handle this task?

Comment: Use a sequence of an `identity` column

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `IDENTITY` column or a `SEQUENCE`.

### Identity Column Example

```
create table t (
  id int primary key not null generated always as identity,
  name varchar(10)
);

insert into t (name) values ('New York');

insert into t (name) values ('Chicago');
```

Result:

```
 id  name     
 --- -------- 
 1   New York 
 2   Chicago
```

Each `INSERT` statement will produce a different value for the `id` column, even when they are executed on separate simultaneous threads.

### Sequence Example

```
create table u (
  id int primary key not null,
  name varchar(10)
);

create sequence sequ;

insert into u (id, name) values (nextval('sequ'), 'New York');

insert into u (id, name) values (nextval('sequ'), 'Chicago');
```

Result:

```
 id  name     
 --- -------- 
 1   New York 
 2   Chicago
```

Again, each `INSERT` statement will produce a different value for the `id` column, even when they are executed on separate simultaneous threads.

See running example for both cases at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mKJo9nhDkQFczq997uLBQy/0).